# PHP writing out PNGs, consistent problem in IE8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, header, png

If I call:
http://localhost/info/imgfeed.php?img=deer.png in the IE address bar then it is displayed fine.

If I link the URLs in an HTML file like this:

```
<img src="imgfeed.php?img=dove.png" alt="" height="" width="" />
<img src="imgfeed.php?img=dolphin.png" alt="" height="" width="" />
<img src="imgfeed.php?img=deer.png" alt="" height="" width="" />
```

Then it fails miserably on IE but works fine on other browsers (tested Chrome/FF in newest stable releases).
My PHP code is as follows (almost verbatim copy from PHP manual):

```
<?php
$server = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
write_img($server.'/'.$path.'/'.$_GET["img"]);

function write_img($filename) {
  $size = getimagesize($filename);
  if ($size && $fp) {
    header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Expires: -1");
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
  } else {
    // error
  }
}
?>
```

Any ideas as to what is going on would be highly appreciated, i tried a range of tricks with headers as well as with .htaccess (making the PHP file appear as a PNG) but none of this has any effect on rendering in IE which ultimately only ever shows 3 minuscule dots (that can be saved as untitled.bmp).

**Update** problem solved courtesy of Meagar (remove width/height from HTML and all is good). Example above updated to reflect advice from Marc B on fpassthru vs readfile.

Comment: ummm...  What's it doing in IE that you say is "failing miserably"?  Oh, and do you realize that by setting `height=""` and `width=""` may be interpreted as 0 height/width?  If you want them to be automatic (based upon the image size), don't even include them in attributes...

Comment: Further to this IE has a tendency to add borders to images if you do not specify border="0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried omitting the `width` and `height` attributes for your `<img>` tag? The server-side code is almost certainly fine; IE is likely interpreting `width=""` as `width="0"` and displaying the tiny dots you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot meagar! Classic example of (me!) jumping through all the most technical hoops before coming to simple solution. Whether I delete the width and height or fill them out with correct values it comes to same result - functional display :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding some more headers which sometimes seem to fix IE issues:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```

But as meagar says, IE6 doesn't like blank width and height attributes, and always requires a value in there.

Comment: The example works with the headers currently set but I'll keep these in mind in case issues when I implement this code in the app I'm working on. It is not just IE6 not liking blank width/height, it is now verified beyond doubt that IE8 goes haywire on it as well.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed - looks like I can join the jumping-into-the-overly-technical-explanations club with you :-)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

```
imagepng($output);
```

for rendering the image?

also it can help to use

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

before fpassthru($fp); to clean the buffer before rendering.

Comment: please format the code segments in your reply. there's a button above the textarea for that.

Comment: fpassthru's a bad choice overall, as it'll load the whole file into memory before sending it. readfile()'s more appropriate, as it'll read/send in chunks. As well, using imagepng() would mean having to first uncompress the image into memory, and then recompressing for output. This might fix any bad data in the source image, but will suck up memory like crazy and put a heavy load on the server.

Comment: @Marc B, thanks for advice on fpassthru; I've updated example accordingly.